# document.save() and res.redirect before function is complete in try/catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I have some struggles with a conversion function I'm using. As my Mongodb documents saves before the conversion is complete which ends up with an array being empty, which should include my URLs(is verified in the callback). Everything is working fine, but my problem is that I redirect and save document way before apiInstance.convertDocumentPptxToPng is finished.

```
try {
 const params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket', 
  Key: req.file.key
 }

await s3.getObject(params, async function(err, data) {
 if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
 else {
  const inputFile = await Buffer.from(data.Body)
  apiInstance.convertDocumentPptxToPng(inputFile, callback)
 }

await course.save()
res.redirect('/course/admin')

})} catch(err) {
console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Is `apiInstance.convertDocumentPptxToPng` an async method? If so then you should `await` it, just like you're doing with all the other async methods in that code.

Comment: if I await this I get an error from aws superagent:

Warning: superagent request was sent twice, because both .end() and .then() were called. Never call .end() if you use promises
Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent
superagent: double callback bug

Comment: Ok. That message appears to be from a different part of the code, or from inside a function being called from this code. I assume it gave you a line number and filename?

Comment: Yes, it's from the callback. But I can't figure out why. If I run this code, the document is converted and imageurl's are returned correctly and pushed to the course object. But await course.save() and res.redirect is called too soon.

Comment: I still have not solved this. So if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `callback`, in this code? It's a function, I guess? What does it do? Can you `await apiInstance.convertDocumentPptxToPng(inputFile)` instead of providing the callback? It depends if that function supports await of course. If not, then you'll have to do the saving and redirecting within the callback.

Comment: Or you could Promisify that function as well, like the call to s3.getObject in the answer below.

Comment: callback does actually a lot.. and it's messy. after I call the `convertDocumentPptxToPng()` method, I get an array of strings back with URLs to the .png files. I then proceed to asynchronously download theese files to my server, then when complete upload them all to the S3 storage, saved with a prefix for the specifed course I'm creating.

I guess the problem is that I'm unable to make the `apiInstance.convertDocumentPptxToPng(inputFile, callback)` async?

Comment: Yes. So as I said, either wrap it in a promise, or just move the save and redirect calls to be at the end of the callback.

Comment: I'll try that. Appreciate the response, thanks.

Comment: Solved by placing `await course.save()` and `res.redirect('/course/admin')` inside `callback` - appreciate the help ADyson and Jeremy!

Answer (score 1):

You are awaiting `s3.getObject`, but you are also giving it a callback function. Remove the callback function and just use await.
`course` is undefined, not sure it's normal though.

```
try {
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket',
        Key: req.file.key
    }

    const data = await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => s3.getObject(params,(err, data) => resolve(data)));

    const inputFile = await Buffer.from(data.Body);
    apiInstance.convertDocumentPptxToPng(inputFile, callback);
    await course.save();
    res.redirect('/course/admin');
    
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: If I remove the callback, I recieve no buffer from the data.Body property. inputFile = undefined.

`course` is outside the try block.

Comment: Ah, `s3.getObject` doesn't return a Promise, it seems. A shame. Alright, I have promisified it

Comment: Tried your promisified solution. We now have data in the buffer `inputFile`, but exact same redirect and save issue as in my code, instant redirect and save. 

On `apiInstance.convertDocumentPptxToPng` callback, I'm logging the course object and it contains the converted images in an array correctly.